# Correct Usage of Alignat -- Partial Overlapping

Tags: vertical-alignment, align, alignat

I am struggling with a certain usage of `alignat`. (I appreciate that there is lots of material online on the usage, but even with that I am unable to solve this.)

Let me give a MWE.

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}

\begin{alignat*}{2}
    &\text{by some long reference... ... ...},
&\quad
    a &= b;
\\
    &\text{by Lem1},
&\quad
    a_1 + a_2 + a_3 - b_2 - b_3 &= b_1.
\end{alignat*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I want the two equals signs `=` to be aligned, and the two `by`s to be aligned (left). However, I don't want the big white space in the centre. I want the long text on the first line to overlap the long equation on the second. (I have tried to indicate this with arrows ion the picture.)

If someone can help me out with a solution, that would be great! Even better, if they could explain *why*/*how* it works -- I do struggle a bit with `alignat` in general, and want to learn more!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, the right edge of `\text{by some long reference... ... ...},` touches the left edge of `\quad a_1 + a_2 + a_3 - b_2 - b_3`, hence creates the unwanted *horizontal* spaces.

One way to solve this is to put the overly-long part into a box, and specify a narrower width for that box (for example, the box below is `0pt` wide; that is, the box does not occupy any space):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

Make the second line exactly separated by a \verb|\quad|:
\begin{alignat*}{2}
    &\makebox[0pt][l]{by some long reference... ... ...,}
&\quad
    a &= b;
\\
    &\text{by Lem1},
&\quad
    a_1 + a_2 + a_3 - b_2 - b_3 &= b_1.
\end{alignat*}
Or make the first line exactly separated by a \verb|\quad|:
\begin{alignat*}{2}
    &\text{by some long reference... ... ...,}
&\quad
    a &= b;
\\
    &\text{by Lem1},
&\quad
    \makebox[0pt][r]{$\displaystyle a_1 + a_2 + a_3 - b_2 - b_3$} &= b_1.
\end{alignat*}

\end{document}
```

[image: two alignat solutions]

Considered that this is a rather unusual layout (since the explaining text usually appears on the right), you will have to decide which line to change.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I agree that it is somewhat unusual. It's just unfortunate that I have long explaining text with the short equation. I would like the spacing to literally be `\text{by Lem1} \quad $a_1 + ...`. Is there some what that I can write `\makebox[\widthof{\text{by Lem1,}}][l]{...`? -- ie force the box to have the width it would have if it were `\text{by Lem1,}`?

Comment: @SamT It’s up to you. For my taste, I would argue that, in the first line, the text and the `a=b` are too close (they are less than a `\quad` apart with your sample text). My preferred alternative is `\makebox[0pt][r]{$a_1 + a_2 + a_3 - b_2 - b_3$}` in the second line. But again, this is just personal preference.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I think your misunderstood my (follow up) question. I was asking how I can force the `makebox` to be of the same size as `\text{by Lem1}` -- you have just put `3em`, which is an approximation

Comment: @SamT Yes, the `3em` is an approximation. But you don’t need an exact value. Any value that is *less than or equal to* the natural length of `\text{by Lem1},` is okay to use here. Because what `alignat` cares about is the widest cell in each column (in this case you have `\text{by Lem1},` being the widest). If you really want to “force” `\text{by Lem1},`, then you can even say `\makebox[0pt][l]{by some long reference... ... ...,}`.

Comment: Maybe it's just my eyes deceiving me, but it seems to me that the space between `...,` and `a = ...` is much less than `\quad`... :/

Comment: @SamT It *IS* less than a `\quad`. This was what I pointed out in my first comment. If you want the first line to have a `\quad` separation, you should put the second line `a_1+...` into a box; but you said you wanted the second line to have exactly `\quad` separation. You cannot expect both lines having `\quad` at the same time (unless for coincidence), so it's up to you to decide which line gets the `\quad`.

Comment: Ah, sorry! I clearly didn't explain well. I meant that I wanted _at least_ a `\quad`! If one replaces `by some long reference... ... ...,` with `by some extremely long reference with many parts,` then there should be a `\quad` after this and a really quite large gap on the second line. I have tried playing around with it some more using your suggestions, but I still can't get there :( -- it seems to me that it should be relatively simple... maybe I'm just being slow! (I don't use them, but even I could do this on OO/LO/Word!)

Comment: @SamT I added an alternative solution to the “at least one `\quad`” layout. See the updated answer for more details `:)`

Comment: Ah, thank you! The key was to use `0pt` and `r`ight align, yeah? I was trying stuff with `rlap` and `rmathlap`, but unsuccessfully. Thanks very much for all your help!! =D